# Get next and previous row from record set

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to retrieve the next row in my database using Codeigniter's active record.

**Model**

```
public function getNextRow()
{
    $this->db->where('id', 1);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('portfolio_shots');
    return $query->next_row();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function test()
{
    $nxt = $this->Portfolio_model->getNextRow();
    echo $nxt->id;
}
```

**Output**

Why am I getting the error

> "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`next_row()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=next_row#CI_DB_result::next_row) returns:

> Next row of result set, or NULL if it doesn’t exist:

so, if there is no next result set, you get the error

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

because `$nxt` is null and not a result set and therefore you cannot `$nxt->id;`

you get into this situation, **because your result set is limited by your query to 1 row only** (therefore no more rows)

anyway you can handle this in your model (removing limits):

```
public function getNextRow()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('portfolio_shots');
    return $query->next_row();
}
```

and in the controller (handle case if last row was reached):

```
public function test()
{
    $nxt = $this->Portfolio_model->getNextRow();
    if($nxt){
      $nxt->id;
    }else{
      echo 'EOF';
    }
}
```